# Warning for sending uiviewcontroller strong to parameter of incompatible type id

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have set delegate like this and I got the warning. If I put WSHelperDelegate, it will silence. However, in this case, I need to use general case like UIVIewController instead of telling specific view controller. How can I silence this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a couple of options here to solve that:

## 1.

```
+ (void)request... {

    // ...
    [[NSHelper sharedInstance] getDetailDataWithEntity:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", url, articleID] andView:vc.view andDelegate:(UIViewController<WSHelperDelegate> *)vc];

}
```

## 2.

```
+ (void)requestEditDataWithArticleId:(NSString *)articleId andNavType:(NavTypeCollection)navType andDelegate:(UIViewController<WSHelperDelegate> *)vc {

   // ...
   [[NSHelper sharedInstance] getDetailDataWithEntity:...];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the controller conform to the delegate you are using:

Ex:

```
@interface yourController : UIViewController <WSHelperDelegate> 
//or <WSHelperProtocol>, whatever it is named.
```

Or you could silence the warning by:

```
....andDelegate:(id)vc];
```

Comment: I don't have interface for that code. It is written in NSObject class. That function will be called from any place.